# In org-tags-view, how can I only see headlines with non-inherited tags?

Tags: org-mode

I want to search my diary folder for all items with the tag `:meeting:`

Here's an example of one such file:

*2021-01-01.org*

```
* meeting with boss :meeting:
** regarding project
  we're running late
** regarding my employment
  i'm fired
```

When I do `M-x org-tags-view` and match for `meeting`, I see a buffer that looks like:

```
Headlines with TAGS match: meeting
Press ‘C-u r’ to search again
  2021-01-01:        meeting with boss :meeting:
  2021-01-01:        regarding project :meeting:
  2021-01-01:        regarding my employment :meeting:
```

I'd like to make it so I only see the headline that has the `meeting` tag applied, not child headlines that inherit the `meeting`. I want my view to look like:

```
Headlines with TAGS match: meeting
Press ‘C-u r’ to search again
  2021-01-01:        meeting with boss :meeting:
```

I've read through the [org-mode tags](https://orgmode.org/guide/Tags.html) documentation, as well as [matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/guide/Matching-Tags-and-Properties.html) and [the agenda dispatcher](https://orgmode.org/guide/Agenda-Dispatcher.html). I've also search Stackoverflow and the internet, and haven't found anyway to do this. Is this possible?

EDIT: I've discovered [the tag inheritance](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-Inheritance.html) docs page, and it says I can try setting `org-agenda-use-tag-inheritance`. It gives me three options for "agenda type" if I do this: "todo," "agenda," and "search." I'm not sure what an "agenda type" is, but I know I want tag inheritance for agenda views, and I'm pretty sure I want them for "TODO" views. I tried removing it for "search" views but that didn't change anything about the output of my tags search, so I don't know if this is what will help me.

EDIT: I can customize `org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance` to exclude the `meeting` tag from being inherited. It does accomplish what I want, but only from this tag, and will force me to for example use combined tags to allow for inheritance when I want it vs not, so for example I'll probably now include a `meeting-inherited` or similar type tag on all things tagged with `meeting` in case I need to display an agenda view with a `TODO` that matches for `meeting` (in this case `meeting-inherited`. It's not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```lisp
(setq org-tags-match-list-sublevels nil)
```

The doc string for the variable (`C-h v org-tags-match-list-sublevels`) says:

```
Non-nil means list also sublevels of headlines matching a search.
This variable applies to tags/property searches, and also to stuck
projects because this search is based on a tags match as well.

When set to the symbol ‘indented’, sublevels are indented with
leading dots.

Because of tag inheritance (see variable ‘org-use-tag-inheritance’),
the sublevels of a headline matching a tag search often also match
the same search.  Listing all of them can create very long lists.
Setting this variable to nil causes subtrees of a match to be skipped.

This variable is semi-obsolete and probably should always be true.  It
is better to limit inheritance to certain tags using the variables
‘org-use-tag-inheritance’ and ‘org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance’.
```

Even though the variable is declared `semi-obsolete`, the suggested replacements are the ones that you have investigated and found wanting, so setting this variable might be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own `org-tags-view` function that turns off inheritance for its duration, but does not otherwise change anything else:

```el
(defun my/org-tags-view (&optional todo-only watch)
  (let ((org-use-tag-inheritance nil))
    (org-tags-view todo-only watch)))
```

If you *always* want to use this function *instead* of the standard `org-tags-view`, you can advise `org-tags-view`:

```el
(advice-add 'org-tags-view :around
              (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
                (let ((org-use-tag-inheritance nil))
                  (apply orig-fun args))))
```

Do `C-h i g(elisp)Advising Functions` to read more about the advice mechanism.

Untested.